# Is there a way to compute a variable with hierarchy in its categories?

Tags: r, case, data-transform

I want to compute a variable with a hierarchical order in its values? Here is a slice of a fake dataset for this purpose.

```
study_id    covid_result    days_from_death time0_death indexyear
999100  N   -7  0   2022
999101  C   9   0   2022
999101  N   -3  0   2021
999102  N   -87 0   2020
999103  N   -89 0   2022
999103  N   1   0   2021
999103  P   0   0   2020
999104  C   -98 0   2020
999104  N   -64 0   2020
999105  P   4   0   2021
999106  P   0   0   2021
999107  N   -84 0   2022
999108  N   -95 0   2020
999108  P   -45 0   2020
999109  N   -2  0   2022
```

My objective is to create a variable `covid_status_death` (covid-19 status at death) with three categories: `positive`, `negative`, `other`. Each person could have more than one covid results, hence, >1 row.

(1) A person will be labelled as covid-positive if they had a positive covid result (covid_result = P) at anytime between -30 days before to 7 days after death. (2) A person will be labelled as covid-negative if they had negative covid results in the absence of a positive test within the same time window. (3) rest will be categorized as other.

What is the best way to approach this problem? I have tried the `case_when()` approach, but I cannot figure out a way to introduce hierarchy, as described above. Please see the attached code below:

```
coviddata %>% mutate(covid_status_death = case_when(
    covid_result == "P" & between(days_from_death,-30,7)~"Positive",
    covid_result == "N" & between(days_from_death,-30,7)~"Negative",
    TRUE ~"other"))
```

I am new to R programming and any help will be much appreciated.
Tony

Comment: please provide a reproducible example of your dataset ( you can use dput() function to get a reproducible data). also not very clear how the output should look like- may be add an image or example of the top 6 rows.

Comment: What do you mean with hierarchy? Should `covid_status_death`  just be ordinally scaled?

Comment: what happens if they have a positive test within the window then a negative test afterwards?

Comment: Hi George, I am sorry for not being clear. A positive test within the window (regardless of a negative test afterwards) qualifies as covid_status_death = positive. In other  words, P-N-N = positive. To be considered negative, they have to have all negatives within the window.